# Incorporate directive's functionality into Angular form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have two questions that are related:

**First:** I have the following directive, who's purpose is to validate whether an `input[type=file]` is valid or not, however I have no idea how it does it least of all, what the actual code means, here it is:

```
angular.module('sccateringApp')
  .directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;
              element.bind('change', function(){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                      modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                  });
              });
          }
      };
  }]);
```

Like I said, I have no idea what the above code actually does, the explanation I got from the forum where I copied that was that it validated an input type file. Is this correct? (So far I haven't been able to verify if it works or not since it doesn't work with the code I'm using at the moment to validate my forms).

**Second:** Having the form below, using angular form validation it doesn't allow the submit button to be clicked until the actual inputs inside the form match the validation rules (enter a name for the category, and the description should have a max length of 144 characters). I included the directive into the file input, however the actual ng-model for the form ignores the required in the input type file and just verifies the rules are met for the first two inputs.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" role="form" name="newCategoryForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                <div input-field>
                                    <input type="text" name="cat-name" id="cat-name" ng-class="{ 'ng-invalid' : newCategoryForm.catname.$invalid && !newCategoryForm.catname.$pristine }"
                                    ng-model="catname" required>
                                    <label>Nombre</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                <div input-field>
                                    <textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="cat-description" id="cat-description" length="144"
                                    ng-model="catdescription" ng-maxlength="144" required></textarea>
                                    <label>Descripción</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                <h6>Imagen de Fondo</h6>
                                <div class="file-field input-field">
                                    <div class="btn pink darken-2 waves-effect waves-light">
                                        <span>Archivo</span>
                                        <input type="file" name="cat-bgimg" id="cat-bgimg"
                                        file-model="variable" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                        <input class="file-path" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large pink darken-2 waves-effect waves-light center-button" ng-disabled="newCategoryForm.$invalid">Crear Categoría</button>
                </form>
```

The first two inputs get validated correctly, the third one (file input) doesn't and I don't really know why since the directive got included on the input (I know natively, ngModel doesn't validate file inputs).

Any ideas or suggestions of how can I fix this? I'm really new to Angular, and all the tutorials are pretty much useless. I come from 5 years of experience working on jQuery, and the transition to Angular hasn't been easy at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive posted above is used to make the submit get the data found in the `<input type="file"></input>`.

Also, a variable should be initialized in the controller so that the values found inside the form are copied to said variable, then this variable needs to be sent as a parameter inside the `ng-submit="submitForm()`.

Example:

```
angular.module('sccateringApp')
  .controller('newSubcategoryController', function (httpcalls, $scope) {
    ...
    $scope.subcategory = [];
    ...
    $scope.submitForm = function(subcategory){
      ...
      $scope.request.insertSubcategory(subcategory);
    }
  });
```

Each ng-model inside the form would be:

`<input type="text" ng-model="category.name">`

So that the category variable found in the controller acquires that value.